# Type multiline equation in a table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

Who knows the way to write a `multiline` equation in a table? I am using the code below:

```
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|}
\hline %inserts horizontal line

&f1& f2 \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline 
a& b& c\\ \hline 
d& e & f  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{label 1}
\end{table}
```

But `b` and `e` are two or maybe three line equations. How can I write them in my table?

Comment: use a `p`-column instead of `c`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|}
\hline %inserts horizontal line
&f1& f2 \\[0.5ex] 
\hline 
a& $\begin{array} {lcl} f(x) & = & (a+b)^2 \\ & = & a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{array}$ & c\\ 
\hline 
d& $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} f(x) & {}= (a+b)^2 \\ & {}= a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{array}$ & f\\    \hline 
g& $\begin{aligned} f(x) & = (a+b)^2 \\ & = a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{aligned}$ &h \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{label 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The above code yields:

[image]

I know it is not the best but I hope it answers your question. I edited the answer as per Peter Grill's suggestion. It is a better math display.

Comment: You can obtain proper math spacing with `$\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} f(x) & {}= (a+b)^2 \\ & {}= a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{array}$`, or just `$\begin{aligned}  f(x) & = (a+b)^2 \\ & = a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{aligned}$`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `\displaystyle` is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
a& b& c\\
$v=mv^2/2$ & $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ & $\displaystyle \frac{mv^2}{2}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that `\dfrac` is standard LaTeX, is it?

Comment: `\dfrac` is the same thing as `\displaystyle \frac{}{}`.

Comment: @NormanGray -- `\dfrac` requires the use of the `amsmath` package.